# Getting Error while adding a component to App component of React

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'


const Greet=()=>  <h1>Say helllo</h1>


export default Greet;
```

This functional component i've created and imported in App.js

```
    import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css';
    import './Components/Greet'

    function App() {
    return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
        <br></br>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </header>
      <Greet/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

*But getting error in chrome web*:

**src\App.js
Line 24:8:  'Greet' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

src\Components\Greet.js
Line 7:16:  'Greet' is not defined  no-undef**

New to React Helpful if someone can help me with this.

Comment: in **src** folder **Components** folder is there in it Greet.js

Answer (score 0):

```
const greet=()=>  <h1>Say helllo</h1>
```

Try `Greet` instead of `greet`

Also in your App.js write in this way

```
import Greet from "./Components/Greet";
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but still its the same after changing to Greet on everywhere, can u help me with it.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the new code that you tried. I will give it another try.

Comment: can you help me out with this